# enums vs direct fields in java

Tags: java, enums

I wanted to understand the best approach out of the below two Options:

**Option (1): (Direct fields which do not use any enums)**

```
public Class FlightDetails {

    private Date scheduledDepartureDateTimeFromX;

    private Date scheduledDepartureDateTimeFromY;

    private Date actualDepartureDateTimeFromX;

    private Date actualDepartureDateTimeFromY;

    private Date scheduledArrivalDateTimeFromX;

    private Date scheduledArrivalDateTimeFromY;

    // etc...
    //getters and setters
}
```

**Option (2) : (Uses many enum types to create FlightDetails)**

```
public enum FlightEventType {
    DEPARTURE, ARRIVAL
}
public enum FlightTimeType {
    SCHEDULED, ACTUAL
}
public enum FlightDetailsSourceType {
    X, Y
}
public Class FlightDetailsType {
    private FlightEventType flightEventType;
    private FlightTimeType flightTimeType;
    private FlightInformationSourceType flightInformationSourceType;
    private Date flightDateTime;

    public FlightDetailsType(FlightEventType flightEventType, 
           FlightTimeType flightTimeType, FlightInformationSourceType  
  flightInformationSourceType, Date flightDateTime) {
        //set the instance variables
    }
    //getters
}


public Class FlightDetails {

    private List<FlightDetailsType> flightDetails;
    //getters and setters

    public FlightDetailsType findFlightDetails(List<FlightDetailsType> 
         flightDetails, FlightEventType flightEventType,
         FlightTimeType flightTimeType, 
         FlightInformationSourceType 
               flightInformationSourceType) {
         //iterate through list and return 
    }
}
```

In my opinion, Option(2) is more flexible, **but at a cost of losing direct access to the field** i.e., we will be having a single list (`List<FlightDetailsType> flightDetails`) which needs to be 
iterated every time to get/retrieve any particular element (like scheduledArrivalDateTimeFromX), which is what `findFlightDetails` method does above.

So which option is the best and why?

Comment: In option 2 you can still have the same get methods as in option 1, you just need to code them differently. You can avoid iteration with use of nested `EnumMap`. That said, if the time data you need to store are always the 6 items in option 1, I might still prefer option 1. Both are certainly viable.

Comment: Option 2 is more flexible alright. Do you consider there is any probability that you will need this greater flexibility at some point? They say you should design for your present requirements, not for some you don’t know whether will ever be.

Comment: PS If you can use Java 8, you should probably prefer `Instant` (or maybe even `OffsetDateTime`)  over `Date`.

Comment: Where are the date values in the second option?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils date value is part of `FlightDetailsType`, added above

Comment: I'm missing some indication that tells me how to judge which is the best answer or comment. Could you provide some insights? How is *FlightDetails* typically called? Or is *FlightDetails* the only usage scenario? Also some hints about non-functional requirements like performance, extensibility, memory footprint would be great. At least, which non-functional is highest priority for you.